# How to solve such an expression involving complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have three complex numbers $ g , h, f$ and one constant $\alpha$. I know that the square of absolute value of product of $\alpha,g ,f$ i.e.,$|\alpha*g*f|^{2}$  can be expressed as $\alpha^2|g*f|$. So how the expression $|h+\alpha*g*f|^2$ can be simplified. Can i use $(a+b)^2$ formula in this case. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: $|a+b|^{2}|=|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}+2 \Re ({a\overline b})$

Comment: Ok.....got it....

Comment: Note: Better to use \cdot (as in $\alpha\cdot f\cdot g$), or simple juxtaposition (as in $\alpha f g$), instead of asterisk, to indicate multiplication.